# Appcelerator 4.1.2 Titanium SDK 4.1.0GA - My Helloworld is not working on android emulator

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, appcelerator

The problem here is my HelloWorld program is working good in the browser, But the problem here is unable to run on the android emulator.

```
 var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
   backgroundColor : 'white'
 });
var myLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
  text : 'Hello World',
  top : 250
});
win.add(myLabel);
win.open();
```

Tthe error here is i.e from log file
-- Start application log -----------------------------------------------------
[INFO] :   TiApplication: (main) [1,1] checkpoint, app created.
[INFO] :   TiApplication: (main) [20280,20281] Titanium 4.1.0 (2015/07/06 11:15 d57aa7d)
[INFO] :   TiApplication: (main) [3193,23474] Titanium Javascript runtime: v8
[INFO] :   TiRootActivity: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity create, savedInstanceState: null
[WARN] :   V8Object: (KrollRuntimeThread) [8947,8947] Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent'
[INFO] :   I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 5.058MB for 1088872-byte allocation
[INFO] :   TiRootActivity: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity resume. activity = com.mss.helloWorld.HelloworldActivity@b3db3380
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [11473,11473] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [5,11478] - In app.js:567,13
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [9,11487] - Message: Uncaught Error: [LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable @ 10.0.2.2:8324
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: [LiveView] Please ensure your device and computer are on the same network and the port is not blocked.
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [3,11490] - Source:       throw new Error('[LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable @
[INFO] :   APSAnalyticsService: Analytics Service Started
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 568: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
[INFO] :   dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 590: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: Exception occurred at app.js:567: Uncaught Error: [LiveView] File Server unavailable. Host Unreachable @ 10.0.2.2:8324
[ERROR] :  V8Exception: [LiveView] Please ensure your device and computer are on the same network and the port is not blocked.
[INFO] :   Choreographer: Skipped 309 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
[INFO] :   APSAnalyticsService: Stopping Analytics Service

Answer (score 1):

This will work if you turn off Liveview (unclick the liveview button on the menu bars)